# how to solve a random selection problem?

Tags: probability, statistics

I need help with a statistics problem, it is for a test but the subject is not mentioned, I have tried to search for information, but I have not found anything clear

A brand of chocolates offers a promotion by giving away chocolates in packages that have “You won. Claim your chocolate bar at the nearest store ”. A quarter of the production distributed by the region is marked with a prize.

If Juan buys two chocolates, the probability that he has at least one free chocolate is?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: hello I have answered your question, is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting at least $1$ free chocolate is opposite the probability of getting no free chocolates. That means that if the probability of getting at least $1$ free chocolate is $1$, the probability of getting no free chocolates is $0$. Thus, the sum of these probabilities is always $1$.

We know that the probability of getting a free chocolate prize is $1/4$. That means the probability of NOT getting a free chocolate prize is $3/4$. So, the probability of getting no free chocolates at all is $3/4$ * $3/4$ $=$ $9/16$. Thus, since the probability of getting no chocolates free and the probability of getting at least one free chocolate is equal to $1$, that means the probability of getting at least $1$ free chocolate is $7/16$ because $7/16$ + $9/16$ = $1$.

Comment: @Algun chico I still have doubts, because it is multiplied 3/4 * 3/4, is it because it is a simultaneous event? That is, 3/4 * 3/4  would be the probability that none of the 2 chocolates was awarded?

Comment: Correct, you multiply the probabilities since they are independent events